# Can I getting the ACCESS MODES supported by storageclasses.storage.k8s.io?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver

For example I want to create a pvc with RWX ACCESS_MODE and can I know in advance if default sorageclasses supports RWX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by Kubernetes. You have to manually find what access modes are supported by your storage class.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from scratch - I advice you to read official documentation about [StorageClasses](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/).

> A StorageClass provides a way for administrators to describe the  "classes" of storage they offer. Different classes might map to quality-of-service levels, or to backup policies, or to arbitrary policies determined by the cluster administrators. **Kubernetes itself is unopinionated about what classes represent. This concept is sometimes called "profiles" in other storage systems.** Each StorageClass contains the fields `provisioner`, `parameters`, and `reclaimPolicy`, which are used when a PersistentVolume belonging to the class needs to be dynamically provisioned.

Take a look on [volume plugins(aka provisioners)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner).

> Each StorageClass has a provisioner that determines what volume plugin
> is used for provisioning PVs. This field must be specified. You are
> not restricted to specifying the "internal" provisioners listed here
> (whose names are prefixed with "kubernetes.io" and shipped alongside
> Kubernetes). You can also run and specify external provisioners, which
> are independent programs that follow a
> [specification](https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/design-proposals/storage/volume-provisioning.md)
> defined by Kubernetes.

Important feature is  [mount-option](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#mount-options).

> PersistentVolumes that are dynamically created by a StorageClass will
> have the mount options specified in the  `mountOptions`  field of the class. If the volume plugin does not support mount options but mount options are specified, provisioning will fail. Mount options are not validated on either the class or PV, so mount of the PV will simply fail if one is invalid.

Finally you have to manually check access modes for resources. Firstly check which StorageClass is set by default:

```
$ kubectl get storageclass
```

Then get information about it:

```
$ kubectl describe storageclass <your-default-storage-class>
```

Now you will be able to check volume plugin and its mount option and access mode. It specific storage class doesn't support wanted access mode mark different storageclass as default:

```sh
$ kubectl patch storageclass <your-storage-class> -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}'
```

Please note that at most one StorageClass can be marked as default. If two or more of them are marked as default, a `PersistentVolumeClaim` without `storageClassName` explicitly specified cannot be created. A cluster administrator can define as many `StorageClass` objects as needed.
See more: [changing-default-storageclass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/#changing-the-default-storageclass).

Comment: I have edited my answer, did you take a look ?